# JAVA_LDAP: Removing user from group

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I am trying to remove a user from an LDAP group using a java code. Though it seems to be very simple, but it is throwing error with `member` and `uniquemember` attributes.

```
    public String removeGroupMembership(InitialDirContext ctx, String sGroup, String sMember){
    String status = "";
    System.out.println("entered removeGroupMembership:"+sGroup);
    System.out.println("The memeber to be added is: "+sMember);
    ModificationItem mods[] = new ModificationItem[1];
    mods[0]= new ModificationItem(InitialDirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("member", sMember));
      try {
        ctx.modifyAttributes(sGroup,mods);
        System.out.println("Group Modified");
```

Error - 
1. for member -

> **javax.naming.directory.SchemaViolationException: [LDAP: error code 65 - Failed to find member in mandatory or optional attribute list.];
>   remaining name** 'cn=........'    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3166)     at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3081)    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2888)    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_modifyAttributes(LdapCtx.java:1475)   at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_modifyAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:277)
>     at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:192)
>     at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:181)
>     at
>   javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.modifyAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:167)
>     at
>   test.bulk.RemoveGroupFromUser.removeGroupMembership(RemoveGroupFromUser.java:69)
>     at test.bulk.RemoveGroupFromUser.main(RemoveGroupFromUser.java:32)

2. for uniqueMember -

> **javax.naming.directory.NoSuchAttributeException: [LDAP: error code 16 - One or more values for attribute uniquemember does not exist];
>   remaining name** 'cn=........'    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3156)     at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3081)    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2888)    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_modifyAttributes(LdapCtx.java:1475)   at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_modifyAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:277)
>     at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:192)
>     at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:181)
>     at
>   javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.modifyAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:167)
>     at
>   test.bulk.RemoveGroupFromUser.removeGroupMembership(RemoveGroupFromUser.java:69)
>     at test.bulk.RemoveGroupFromUser.main(RemoveGroupFromUser.java:32)

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure the group entry has 'uniquemember ' or 'member ' attribute.
2. Make sure you pass the complete DN of the member to be deleted.
   Eg: cn=userMember,ou=xy,dc=xyx,dc=xzx
3. Make sure you are authorized (have admin privilege) to delete/update directory entries. Eg. for SunOne LDAP only cn=Directory Manager has the privilege to create/delete/update entries.